Universal approximation theorem for functions in the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$
I have a function $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ on some bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which I want to approximate by some class of neural networks in the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm. I'm looking for a result like this:

There exist a set $N(d,w)$ of neural networks of depth $d$, width $w$ with $\tanh$ activations (and other architectural details) such that, for any  $\epsilon > 0$ and any $ f \in H^1(\Omega)$, there exists a $g \in N(d,w)$ such that
$$\lVert f-g \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \epsilon.$$

I guess this is too strong a result, so something this weaker statement would suffice:

For any  $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a set $N(d,w)$ of neural networks of depth $d$, width $w$ with $\tanh$ activations (and other architectural details) such that, for $ f \in H^1(\Omega)$, there exists a $g \in N(d,w)$ such that
$$\lVert f-g \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \epsilon.$$

Does anyone know if a result like this is true, and any citations?
My literature search only showed a weaker unsatisfactory result: that functions in $H^2(\Omega)$ can be approximated by neural networks in the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm. But my function is only in $H^1$ and I need to approximate it in that norm.
